# tick() inside fakeAsync function is not waiting for promises to resolve

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Consider this service function which retrieves a single Task and wraps the result in a promise.

```
get(id: string): Promise<Task> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.tasks.findOne({_id: id}).exec(function (err, doc) {
        console.log("Getting task: ", doc);
        if (err)
          reject(err);
        else
          resolve(<Task>doc);
        });
    });
}
```

I wrote this unit test for the get function:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    const injector = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [TaskService, Logger]
    });
    subject = injector.get(TaskService);
    var Datastore = require('nedb');
    db = new Datastore({filename: 'test'});

     subject.setDBConnection(db);
    task = new Task();
    task.title = 'Test Task';
    task._id = "TEST";

    db.loadDatabase();

    db.insert(task);

});


it('returns existing record', fakeAsync(() => {
  let r = null;

  subject.get('TEST').then((doc) => {
    r = doc;
    console.log(this.result);

  });

  tick();
  console.log("expectation run", r);
  expect(result).toBeDefined();
  expect(r.title).toEqual('Test Task');

}));
```

For some reason the fakeAsync() and tick() function do not do their job because console output displays "expectations run" before the `then` block prints the result to the console. (typical asynchronous code execution).

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this code to wait for the completion of the promise?

I am following the examples on [this page](https://www.joshmorony.com/testing-asynchronous-code-with-fakeasync-in-angular/). I think the problem is caused by the fact that `get` calls an async function itself and then returns a promise which must be resolved in the test.
Though I don't understand why that should not work because the example in the documentation does the exact same thing in a simplified way such as:

```
it('should test some asynchronous code', fakeAsync(() => {
    let flag = false;
    setTimeout(() => { flag = true; }, 100);
    expect(flag).toBe(false); // PASSES
    tick(50);
    expect(flag).toBe(false); // PASSES
    tick(50);
    expect(flag).toBe(true); // PASSES
}));
```

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue?

Comment: no, never. still doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified how long to simulate the passage of time.

For example, `tick(500)` would wait 500 milliseconds.

```
 get(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
 }
```

This can be tested with following:

```
  it('returns existing record', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.get('TEST').then((x) => {
      console.log('get finished');
    });

    tick(550); // wait 501 ms 

    console.log('expectation run');

    flush();
  }));
```

which prints

```
// get finished
// expectation run
```

In your case, you need to **guess** how long `TaskService` will take to run to guarantee the correct chain of events.

I would suggest using `await`, which will wait until the promise is resolved before executing the next line of code.

```
  it('returns existing record', async () => {
    await component.get('TEST');
    console.log('expectation run');
  });
```